# CSRF Token comparison fails with Spring Security 6

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security

I'm writing an application with a Svelte frontend and a Spring Boot 3 backend (version "3.0.6").

I read about the new protection against the BREACH attack, and I applied the [new configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework) from Spring Security.

On my frontend, before sending any POST request, I read the value of the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie and I copy that value to the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

By debugging the code, I can see that `CsrfFilter` is able to extract the token value from the header.

Unfortunately, the method `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler::getTokenValue` which receives two identical strings as input returns `null`. Given that the input is entirely defined by what my client sends, I guess that I must transform the `XSRF-TOKEN` value before copying it into the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

The method code is:

```
// example call: actualToken = token = "b4b40051-9f64-4d8e-9092-cc84cc769ae0"
private static String getTokenValue(String actualToken, String token) {
    byte[] actualBytes;
    try {
        actualBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(actualToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    byte[] tokenBytes = Utf8.encode(token);
    int tokenSize = tokenBytes.length;
    if (actualBytes.length < tokenSize) {
        // 24 < 36 so we arrive here
        return null;
    }

    // extract token and random bytes
    int randomBytesSize = actualBytes.length - tokenSize;
    byte[] xoredCsrf = new byte[tokenSize];
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[randomBytesSize];

    System.arraycopy(actualBytes, 0, randomBytes, 0, randomBytesSize);
    System.arraycopy(actualBytes, randomBytesSize, xoredCsrf, 0, tokenSize);

    byte[] csrfBytes = xorCsrf(randomBytes, xoredCsrf);
    return Utf8.decode(csrfBytes);
}
```

When everything goes fine, this method is supposed to return the same value as "token" and the call `equalsConstantTime(csrfToken.getToken(), actualToken)` returns `true`, where `actualToken` is the return value of the above method.

So, what am I supposed to do with the value of the cookie `XSRF-TOKEN` before copying it into the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` ?

Comment: By going further into the code, and making sense of what I read about the BREACH protection, I feel like I need to XOR the value with random bytes and prefix the token with the XORed value.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_a_single_page_application_with_httpsessioncsrftokenrepository

Basically, the JavaScript client doesn't need to interact with the cookie at all. Instead, the server can define the endpoint

```
@GetMapping("/csrf")
public CsrfToken csrfToken(CsrfToken csrfToken) {
    return csrfToken;
}
```

Which returns, for example:

```
{
    "parameterName":"_csrf",
    "token":"pKpetTa2tv6yhmnko7ZvtaiP7CgX8cB5uBbR1G-ZR6NiKTpIkcltgALX0J-fslyGkJtbgpG_wRFxl_VUgCDm513_dMVUGQ15",
    "headerName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
}
```

Along with the corresponding raw token in the cookie, which the browser will forward automatically.